# The string inserted into the database is not complete

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a very interesting issue.  Only part of a value is being entered into my database.

I have a page that contains a form.  The user will fill out the form and submit.  All the POST values are correct and are submitting to the database.  One paticular value ($criteria) is only submitting the last part of the string.  If I echo the value of $criteria it is all there but, when I view it in mysqlAdmin only part of it is there.

It should be submitting:

> `Communication | 1 | dsafadf | Customer Service | 2 | asdfadf | Dependability | 3 | asdfadsf | Initiative | 4 | dsafadsfa | Job Knowledge | 5 | dsadafsadsf | Judy | 1 | asdfasdf | Punctuality | 2 | asdfdasdfadsf |`

But in the database I only get - | Punctuality | 2 | asdfdasdfadsf |

I have tried to manually add the value using mysqlAdmin and it works fine.

If there is additional information need to help I will add.

Thanks Everyone!!

---

Here is my insert script:

---

```
      public function insertReview() {
      $fk_employee = $_POST['fk_employee'];

      // Current Date returned from JQuery and formatted to add to DB.
      $cdate = $_POST['current_date'];
      $current_date = explode("/", $cdate);
        $cmonth = $current_date[0];
        $cday = $current_date[1];
        $cyear = $current_date[2];
        $current_dateA = array($cyear, $cmonth, $cday);
      $review_date = implode("-", $current_dateA);

      // Review Begin Date returned from JQuery Datepicker and formatted to add to DB.            
      $bdate = $_POST['r_period_begin'];
      $begin_date = explode("/", $bdate);
        $bmonth = $begin_date[0];
        $bday = $begin_date[1];
        $byear = $begin_date[2];
        $begin_dateA = array($byear, $bmonth, $bday);
      $r_period_begin = implode("-", $begin_dateA);

      // Review End Date returned from JQuery Datepicker and formatted to add to DB.
      $edate = $_POST['r_period_end'];
      $end_date = explode("/", $edate);
        $emonth = $end_date[0];
        $eday = $end_date[1];
        $eyear = $end_date[2];
        $end_dateA = array($eyear, $emonth, $eday);
      $r_period_end = implode("-", $end_dateA);

    // Criteria 
      $criterias = $_POST['criteria'];
      //var_dump($criterias);
      $criteriaValue = $_POST['criteriaValue'];
      //var_dump($criteriaValue);
      $comments = $_POST['Comments'];

      foreach ($criteriaValue as $key => $value ){
          foreach( $criterias as $criteria ){
              if( $criteria == $key ){
                  $string1 = $key;
                  foreach( $comments as $comment => $comm ){
                      if( $string1 == $comment ){
                          $string3 = $comm;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          //echo $key . '<br>';
          foreach ( $value as $result ){
              $string2 = $result;
          }

      $criteria = mysql_real_escape_string( $string1 . ' | ' . $string2 . ' | ' . $string3 . ' | ' );
      echo $criteria;
      }
      // End of Criteria

      $job_knowledge = $_POST['job_knowledge'];
      $jk_comments = $_POST['jk_comments'];
      $work_quality = $_POST['work_quality'];
      $wq_comments = $_POST['wq_comments'];
      $attendance = $_POST['attendance'];
      $attend_comments = $_POST['attend_comments'];
      $initiative = $_POST['initiative'];
      $init_comments = $_POST['init_comments'];
      $communication = $_POST['communication'];
      $comm_comments = $_POST['comm_comments'];
      $dependability = $_POST['dependability'];
      $depend_comments = $_POST['depend_comments'];
      $customer_service = $_POST['customer_service'];
      $cs_comments = $_POST['cs_comments'];
      $overall_rating = $_POST['overall_rating'];
      $additional_comments = $_POST['additional_comments'];
      $goals = $_POST['goals'];

    $conn = parent::connect();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . TBL_EMPLOYEE_REVIEW . " (
              fk_employee,
              review_date,
              r_period_begin,
              r_period_end,
              job_knowledge,
              jk_comments,
              work_quality,
              wq_comments,
              attendance,
              attend_comments,
              initiative,
              init_comments,
              communication,
              comm_comments,
              dependability,
              depend_comments,
              customer_service,
              cs_comments,
              overall_rating,
              additional_comments,
              goals,
              criteria
            ) VALUES (
              :fk_employee,
              :review_date,
              :r_period_begin,
              :r_period_end,
              :job_knowledge,
              :jk_comments,
              :work_quality,
              :wq_comments,
              :attendance,
              :attend_comments,
              :initiative,
              :init_comments,
              :communication,
              :comm_comments,
              :dependability,
              :depend_comments,
              :customer_service,
              :cs_comments,
              :overall_rating,
              :additional_comments,
              :goals,
              :criteria
            )";

    try {
      $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
      $st->bindValue( ":fk_employee", $fk_employee, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":review_date", $review_date, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":r_period_begin", $r_period_begin, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":r_period_end", $r_period_end, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":job_knowledge", $job_knowledge, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":jk_comments", $jk_comments, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":work_quality", $work_quality, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":wq_comments", $wq_comments, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":attendance", $attendance, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":attend_comments", $attend_comments, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":initiative", $initiative, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":init_comments", $init_comments, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":communication", $communication, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":comm_comments", $comm_comments, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":dependability", $dependability, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":depend_comments", $depend_comments, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":customer_service", $customer_service, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":cs_comments", $cs_comments, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":overall_rating", $overall_rating, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":additional_comments", $additional_comments, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":goals", $goals, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $st->bindValue( ":criteria", $criteria, PDO::PARAM_STR );

      $st->execute();
      parent::disconnect( $conn );
    } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
      parent::disconnect( $conn );
      die( "Query failed: " . $e->getMessage() );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you call your insert script once or you have some cycle? Can you please post the code how you call your insert function?

Comment: @middaparka I agree with you, the length of the filed may be not sufficient

Comment: Try printing out the query after inserting it to see if it's correct. If it is, try running it manually on the sql client to see if it inserts the information properly. This will help you figure out if the problem is on the php side or sql side

Comment: I would recommend cutting your script down to show only the relevant code to the `critera` issue.

Comment: I'd look at `foreach ( $value as $result ){ $string2 = $result; }` first.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it might be the culprit:

```
$criteria = mysql_real_escape_string( $string1 . ' | ' . $string2 . ' | ' . $string3 . ' | ' );
```

It's at the end of the foreach() loop:

```
foreach ($criteriaValue as $key => $value ){
    ...

    $criteria = mysql_real_escape_string( $string1 . ' | ' . $string2 . ' | ' . $string3 . ' | ' );
}
```

You're inserting that value directly into the DB here:

```
$st->bindValue( ":criteria", $criteria, PDO::PARAM_STR );
```

But your loop is always creating a string from the last iteration of the loop.  It doesn't appear to be concatenating the previous values.  You prob. need something like this:

```
$criteria .= mysql_real_escape_string( $string1 . ' | ' . $string2 . ' | ' . $string3 . ' | ' );
```

(notice the ".=")

However, you're using `$critera` in your nested foreach loop as well, so you'll have to adjust that bit as well.  Something like this should be easy enough:

```
foreach( $criterias as $crit){
          if( $crit == $key ){
....
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you!! I will give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple logic errors in your loop which sets the value for `$criteria`: you try to loop on `$value` without needing to; if you could, it would always leave `$string2` set as the final `$value`. You also have `$criteria` both as the holder for your second inner foreach loop and what you want to use. Finally you are setting `$critera` with each loop, instead of appending to it, and your output is misleading because you are echoing as you loop, rather than echoing the final result of `$criteria` from outside the loop:

```
 foreach ($criteriaValue as $key => $value ){
          foreach( $criterias as $criteria ){
              if( $criteria == $key ){
                  $string1 = $key;
                  foreach( $comments as $comment => $comm ){
                      if( $string1 == $comment ){
                          $string3 = $comm;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          //echo $key . '
';
          foreach ( $value as $result ){
              $string2 = $result;
          }

      $criteria = mysql_real_escape_string( $string1 . ' | ' . $string2 . ' | ' . $string3 . ' | ' );
      echo $criteria;
      }
```

Should be:

```
foreach ($criteriaValue as $key => $value ){
  foreach( $criterias as $criteriasValue ){
    if( $criteriasValue == $key ){
      $string1 = $key;
      foreach( $comments as $comment => $comm ){
        if( $string1 == $comment ){
          $string3 = $comm;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  $string2 = $result;

  $criteria .= mysql_real_escape_string( $string1 . ' | ' . $string2 . ' | ' . $string3 . ' | ' );

}

echo $criteria;
```

Comment: The first response is what fixed my issue!!  You guys are superb!!  Thank you.  Call closed